# Props typing in Vue.js 3 with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to type hint my props in a Vue 3 component, with composition API.

So, I'm doing this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import FlashInterface from '@/interfaces/FlashInterface';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

export default {
    props: {
        message: {
            type: FlashInterface,
            required: true
        }
    },
    setup(props): Record<string, unknown> {
        // Stuff
    }
};
```

My `FlashInterface` looks like this:

```
export default interface FlashInterface {
    level: string,
    message: string,
    id?: string
}
```

This interface works well except in this case where I got this error:

```
ERROR in src/components/Flash.vue:20:10
TS2693: 'FlashInterface' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
    18 |    props: {
    19 |        message: {
  > 20 |            type: FlashInterface,
       |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    21 |            required: true
    22 |        }
    23 |    },
```

I don't understand why TypeScript thinks this is a value.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 116):

You should use it with `PropType` imported from vue like `Object as PropType<FlashInterface>`:

```
import FlashInterface from '@/interfaces/FlashInterface';
import { ref,PropType, defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        message: {
            type: Object as PropType<FlashInterface>,
            required: true
        }
    },
    setup(props) {
            // Stuff
        }
});
```

**Note :** you should create your component using `defineComponent` in order to get the types inference.

**script setup**

**<Vue3.3** :

You could define the props using `defineProps` function in two ways, but you should declare the types/interfaces inside the script setup as mentioned [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props) :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref,PropType, defineComponent , defineProps} from 'vue';
interface FlashInterface {
    level: string,
    message: string,
    id?: string
}
interface IProps{
   message : FlashInterface
}
const props = defineProps<IProps>()
```

or

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
...
interface FlashInterface {
    level: string,
    message: string,
    id?: string
}
const props = defineProps({
        message: {
            type: Object as PropType<FlashInterface>,
            required: true
        }
    })
```

## Update Vue 3.3+

Set in your `package.json` under `dependencies`

```json
"vue": "^3.3.0"
```

Now the `defineProps<T>()` macro accept an imported interface and you can do this:

```js
import FlashInterface from '@/interfaces/FlashInterface';
import { defineProps } from 'vue';

export default defineProps<FlashInterface>();
```

If you need to specify default values, you can do as follows:

```js
const { 
  message = "No message :(",
  level,
  id,
} = defineProps<FlashInterface>();
```

From the [PR 8083](https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/8083) officially added in Vue 3.3.0

Comment: What about if props type is array? It will be Array as PropType<FlashInterface> or Object as PropType<FleshInterface[]> ??

Comment: @FarhodNematov it should be `type: Array as PropType<FlashInterface[]>,` or `type: Array as PropType<Array<FlashInterface>>,`

Comment: According to the official documentation, using interfaces imported from another file won't make type-checking work. https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props

Answer (score 5):

### Two liner

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import FlashInterface from '@/interfaces/FlashInterface';
defineProps<{flash: FlashInterface;}>();
</script>
```

Comment: Please add more details about your answer

Comment: This CANNOT work. You can't use imported type in defineProps as of today. See https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4294#issuecomment-1316097560

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is complaining about missing a reference for a (custom) constructor during [type checking](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Type-Checks) (links to legacy docs but works the same way with the most recent version of Vue).

In Typescript, you might want to think of interfaces as a contract that an entity should conform to, so they aren't really a constructor, and therefore, we need to provide an **implementation** of those interfaces.

Since you are on Typescript, if you need to keep the interface, consider using the class equivalent:

```
// Name the constructor whatever you like,
// but I would personally prefix interfaces with an "I"
// to distinguish them with the constructors

class Flash implements FlashInterface {
  level: string;
  message: string;
  id?: string

  constructor() {
    // Be sure to initialize the values for non-nullable props
    this.level = '';
    this.message = '';
  }
}

export default {
  name: 'Home',

  props: {
    message: Flash
  }
}
```

An excerpt from the doc:

> In addition, `type` can also be a custom constructor function and the assertion will be made with an `instanceof` check. For example, given the following constructor function exists:

```js
props: {
  message: {
    type: function Person(firstName, lastName) {
      this.firstName = firstName
      this.lastName = lastName
    }
  }
}
```

And of course, another alternative would be as suggested in the other post with `PropType`. Either one will do. It's just a matter of preference, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You can use setup script to define your props

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';
interface FlashInterface {
    level: string,
    message: string,
    id?: string
}
interface Props{
   message:FlashInterface
}
const props = defineProps<Props>()
```

for more information:
[Vue doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-props)

Comment: This CANNOT work. You can't use imported type in defineProps as of today. See https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4294#issuecomment-1316097560

Comment: Yes, You're right. I've seen that in vue document and forgot to change my answer. thanks to point that tip

Answer (score 2):

We should use PropType from 'vue' for Interface that developer created manually and define default value!

```
import FlashInterface from '@/interfaces/FlashInterface';
import { ref,PropType, defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

export default defineComponent({
   props: {
       message: {
           type: Object as PropType<FlashInterface>,
           default: {}
       }
   },
// stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea to get around this by introducing a generic props type and a function to enforce correct implementation of the props.

```
type TypedProps<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: {
     type: PropType<T[key]>
     required?: boolean
  } | PropType<T[key]>
}

function typedProps<T extends object>(props: TypedProps<T>): TypedProps<T> {
  return props
}
```

I would use it in `defineComponents` like this

```
interface MyProps {
  prop1: string
  prop2: CustomInterface
}
export default defineComponent({
  props: typedProps<MyProps>({
    prop1: String,
    prop2: Object as PropType<CustomInterface>
  })
})
```

Though, it does not work as intended with the `required` key. Maybe someone could explain why or propose a correction.

Answer (score 1):

`Object as PropType` strikes me as funky and nearly un-rememberable syntax. A much nicer way of typing properties is to put a generic type argument inline in the defineProps call, so, with `<script setup lang="ts">`...

```
const props = defineProps<{ message: FlashInterface }>()
```