# vue 3 composition api & typescript object keys

Tags: typescript, vue.js, properties, vuejs3

Currently digging into Vue-3 composition api and wondering how to use types in detail (using TypeScript on top of vue).

The [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#using-with-composition-api) isn't very accurate on this, since there is only a short description about how to do Strings. Of course according to that I could simply use type Object, but I wonder how to declare object properties, to tell TypeScript what keys belong to a related object - in class style api this could be done the TypeScript way ... is there any extended source about how to do properties in detail in composition api?

Comment: Maybe provide a little code snippet demonstrating what you're trying to achieve. An example can often illustrate a problem better than a long description.

Comment: In class style api I'd do it this way:


@Prop() somePropertyName: { foo, bar };

So TypeScript/my IDE knows that my Object should contain the keys foo and bar. I could not find any description about how to achieve that using composition api

Comment: ok you need to use `PropType`. I'll give you an example below.

Comment: @IrgendSonHansel Someone asked [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64831745/3634538) recently. My proposed solution there might help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `PropType` to provide strong type definitions for your props. Here's an example ..

```
import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    myProp: Object as PropType<{ foo: string, bar: number }>,
  },
  setup(props) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you tell where this information can be found? Now I know how to handle objects but what about arrays & functions ...?

Comment: @IrgendSonHansel Same thing. See [Annotating Props](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props) in the official guide.