# How can i access child component method in parent component using ref in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, ref

I am trying to access the child method in the parent component using vue3 and ref method. But it returns an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: addNewPaper.value?.savePaper is not a function

Below is my code. Please guide me where i am wrong.

**Child component**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useWindowScroll } from '@vueuse/core'
import { Notyf } from 'notyf'
import { computed, defineProps, reactive, ref } from 'vue'
import { papers } from '/@src/firebase/connections'

const companySize = ref('')
const businessType = ref('')
const productToDemo = ref('')
const date = ref(new Date())

const { y } = useWindowScroll()

const isStuck = computed(() => {
  return y.value > 30
})

const initialState = reactive({
  subject: '',
  paper: '',
  marks: '',
})

const notyf = new Notyf()

const props = defineProps({
  subjects: { required: true },
})

const savePaper = () => {
  papers
    .add(initialState)
    .then(() => {
      notyf.success('Paper saved successfully')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      notyf.error('Something went wrong')
    })
}
</script>
```

**Parent component**

```
const addNewPaper = ref()


const successSave = () => {
  addNewPaper.value?.savePaper()
  notyf.success('Your paper has been successfully created!')
}

 <template #content>
   <FormAddNewTopical ref="addNewPaper" :subjects="_subjects"></FormAddNewTopical>
 </template>
```

Any solution appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Public members are supposed to be defined with [`defineExpose`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose) with `script setup` syntax:

```
defineExpose({ savePaper })
```

Or with `ctx.expose` in [setup function](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#setup-context):

```
setup(props, ctx) {
  ...
  ctx.expose({ savePaper })
  ...
```

Comment: I am trying to use the same but it throws an error `Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'defineExpose'.Vetur(2305)`

Comment: Check the linked documentation, it shows that define functions don't need to be imported, they are parts of script setup syntax. I'm quite sure that defineExpose is compiled to ctx.expose then.

Comment: Cannot find the name `defineExpose`. This is the error now coming. Also same for `ctx`

Comment: Where does the error come from? Does the app compile? You listed Vetur error previously that can behave differently

Comment: This error is coming in Visual studio Editor. App compiled successfully but in console same error coming.

Comment: Does the app runs? Then the problem is specific to the editor, it's a common thing. As for ctx.expose, I added an explanation, there can be no discrepancies if the signature is `setup(props, ctx) {`

Comment: I am using `vite` with vue3.

Comment: App stop working now. It comes with lot of errors. Like `defineExpose` is not defined

Comment: you must've done something wrong - how, exactly, are you using `defineExpose` - if your app has stopped working, undo everything you've done since applying the correct answer given here, and try again

Comment: @RobinSingh Please, specify the exact errors. There's a big difference if it comes from a compiler or an editor, and if it comes from TS at compilation time or JS at runtime. Make sure you use the latest Vue version. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/69999044/3731501