# How to fix defineExpose method not defined in Vue3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, vite

I am trying to pass the method from child to parent. But somehow `defineExpose()` method is not working. Can you please guide me on what I am doing wrong?

If you need more detail then you can refer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72590163/how-can-i-access-child-component-method-in-parent-component-using-ref-in-vue3)

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useHead } from '@vueuse/head'

import { pageTitle } from '/@src/state/sidebarLayoutState'

pageTitle.value = 'Saved Topical'
useHead({
  title: 'Saved Topical',
})

defineExpose({
  
})
</script>
```

```
{
  "name": "vuero",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "private": "true",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "dev:force": "vite --force",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "run-s lint:doc:fix lint:eslint:fix lint:stylelint:fix lint:prettier:fix",
    "lint:prettier": "prettier --check \"./src/**/*.(ts|vue|css|scss)\"",
    "lint:prettier:fix": "prettier --write \"./src/**/*.(ts|vue|css|scss)\"",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint --ext .ts,.vue ./src",
    "lint:eslint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .ts,.vue ./src",
    "lint:stylelint": "stylelint ./src/**/*.{vue,css,scss}",
    "lint:stylelint:fix": "stylelint ./src/**/*.{vue,css,scss} --fix",
    "lint:doc:fix": "run-s lint:doc:fix:*",
    "lint:doc:fix:eslint": "eslint --fix --ext .md ./documentation",
    "lint:doc:fix:prettier": "prettier --write \"./documentation/**/*.(md)\"",
    "test": "run-p test:lint",
    "test:tsc": "vue-tsc --noEmit",
    "test:lint": "run-p lint:eslint lint:stylelint lint:prettier",
    "e2e": "cypress run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "28.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "2.0.1",
    "@iconify/iconify": "2.0.2",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "4.7.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "2.9.2",
    "@vueform/multiselect": "1.5.0",
    "@vueform/slider": "1.0.5",
    "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.41",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.29",
    "@vueuse/core": "5.0.3",
    "@vueuse/head": "0.6.0",
    "apexcharts": "3.27.1",
    "axios": "^0.22.0",
    "billboard.js": "3.0.3",
    "bulma": "0.9.3",
    "dayjs": "1.10.5",
    "dragula": "3.7.3",
    "dropzone": "5.9.2",
    "filepond": "4.28.2",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-size": "2.2.4",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type": "1.2.6",
    "filepond-plugin-image-crop": "2.0.6",
    "filepond-plugin-image-edit": "1.6.3",
    "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation": "1.0.11",
    "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "4.6.6",
    "filepond-plugin-image-resize": "2.0.10",
    "filepond-plugin-image-transform": "3.7.6",
    "firebase": "^9.6.2",
    "imask": "6.0.7",
    "mapbox-gl": "2.3.0",
    "markdown-it-emoji": "2.0.0",
    "notyf": "3.10.0",
    "nprogress": "0.2.0",
    "photoswipe": "4.1.3",
    "simple-datatables": "3.0.2",
    "simplebar": "6.0.0-beta.10",
    "simplebar-vue": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "sweet-modal-vue": "^2.0.0",
    "tiny-slider": "2.9.3",
    "tippy.js": "6.3.1",
    "trim-newlines": "^4.0.2",
    "tslib": "2.3.0",
    "v-calendar": "3.0.0-alpha.4",
    "vue": "3.0.11",
    "vue-i18n": "9.1.4",
    "vue-js-modal": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-router": "4.0.6",
    "vue-scrollto": "2.20.0",
    "vue-tippy": "6.0.0-alpha.29",
    "vue3-apexcharts": "1.4.0",
    "xmodal-vue": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@iconify/json": "1.1.358",
    "@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n": "2.2.1",
    "@types/dragula": "3.7.0",
    "@types/mapbox__mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^4.7.0",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/markdown-it": "12.0.2",
    "@types/node": "15.12.4",
    "@types/nprogress": "0.2.0",
    "@types/prismjs": "1.16.5",
    "@types/simplebar": "5.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.27.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.27.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "1.2.3",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "3.1.1",
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "cypress": "7.5.0",
    "eslint": "7.29.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-md": "1.0.19",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier-vue": "3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "7.11.1",
    "gray-matter": "4.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "11.0.0",
    "markdown-it": "12.0.6",
    "markdown-it-anchor": "8.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "plyr": "3.6.8",
    "prettier": "2.3.1",
    "prismjs": "^1.25.0",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "rollup": "2.52.1",
    "sass": "1.32.13",
    "stylelint": "^14.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "8.0.2",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^24.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.3.4",
    "vite": "2.3.8",
    "vite-imagetools": "3.6.8",
    "vite-plugin-components": "0.11.2",
    "vite-plugin-fonts": "0.2.2",
    "vite-plugin-imagemin": "^0.1.0",
    "vite-plugin-pages": "0.13.2",
    "vite-plugin-purge-icons": "0.7.0",
    "vite-plugin-pwa": "0.8.1",
    "vite-plugin-radar": "0.2.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.3.0",
    "yorkie": "2.0.0"
  },
  "gitHooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.ts": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "*.scss": [
      "stylelint",
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "*.md": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "*.vue": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: Looks like your editor doesn't know Vue3

Comment: @robertklep The same issue comes when i compile in the browser. Now, what are you thinking about the browser?

Comment: All other methods are working fine, only this method show me error.

Comment: `defineExpose()` works fine for me in Vue3 components (but only valid in `<script setup>`), so perhaps you need to show a bit more context. Also, please post actual code instead of images.

Comment: @robertklep i added code snippet, please check now

Comment: It seems that you are using veture extension. Volar is the official vue3 vscode extension which supports typescript as well. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar.
Can you also please include the parent component code?

Comment: @Kalimah i attached a link of my previous question that was same, but not resolved

Comment: @RobinSingh it's not relevant what your editor thinks is valid or not. Like I said, I can use `defineExpose()` just fine in Vue3 components, and I don't see anything inherently wrong in the code you post. What exactly are the browser errors you get?

Comment: @robertklep browser error was `defineExpose()` is not defined. I attached my package.json file. You can check that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue with Vue 3. **Updating my `TypeScript` version** from `4.5.5` to version `4.9.3` magically fixed it. Apparently older TypeScript version don't understand compiler macros like `defineExpose`.

And also to mute the ESLint errors, I had to prefix it (like [@stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10154279/stefan) mentioned) with:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
defineExpose({  });
```

Comment: This is not the good idea to disable errors. You have to fix the errors if any.

Comment: It's not an error, It's just ESLint doesn't understand macros without import (yet). https://github.com/eslint/eslint/discussions/15015

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

vue version must be 3.1.3 or greater because that is when defineExpose was introduced.

https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#313-2021-07-01

---

I am not sure what is wrong with your code because you are adding defineExpose.
Try this code (I changed few variables because I don't have them in my local setup):

**Parent.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { Notyf } from 'notyf';
import Child from './Child.vue';

const addNewPaper = ref();
const notyf = new Notyf();

const successSave = () => {
  addNewPaper.value.savePaper();
  notyf.success('Your paper has been successfully created!');
};
</script>
<template #content>
  <input type="button" @click="successSave" value="Save" />
  <Child ref="addNewPaper"></Child>
</template>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Notyf } from 'notyf';
import { computed, defineProps, reactive, ref } from 'vue';

const companySize = ref('');
const businessType = ref('');
const productToDemo = ref('');
const date = ref(new Date());

const initialState = reactive({
  subject: '',
  paper: '',
  marks: '',
});

const notyf = new Notyf();

const props = defineProps({
  subjects: { required: true },
});

const savePaper = () => {
  notyf.success('Paper saved successfully');
};

defineExpose({
  savePaper,
});
</script>
```

```
{
  "name": "vuero",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "private": "true",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "dev:force": "vite --force",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "run-s lint:doc:fix lint:eslint:fix lint:stylelint:fix lint:prettier:fix",
    "lint:prettier": "prettier --check \"./src/**/*.(ts|vue|css|scss)\"",
    "lint:prettier:fix": "prettier --write \"./src/**/*.(ts|vue|css|scss)\"",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint --ext .ts,.vue ./src",
    "lint:eslint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .ts,.vue ./src",
    "lint:stylelint": "stylelint ./src/**/*.{vue,css,scss}",
    "lint:stylelint:fix": "stylelint ./src/**/*.{vue,css,scss} --fix",
    "lint:doc:fix": "run-s lint:doc:fix:*",
    "lint:doc:fix:eslint": "eslint --fix --ext .md ./documentation",
    "lint:doc:fix:prettier": "prettier --write \"./documentation/**/*.(md)\"",
    "test": "run-p test:lint",
    "test:tsc": "vue-tsc --noEmit",
    "test:lint": "run-p lint:eslint lint:stylelint lint:prettier",
    "e2e": "cypress run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "28.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "2.0.1",
    "@iconify/iconify": "2.0.2",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "4.7.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "2.9.2",
    "@vueform/multiselect": "1.5.0",
    "@vueform/slider": "1.0.5",
    "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.41",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.29",
    "@vueuse/core": "5.0.3",
    "@vueuse/head": "0.6.0",
    "apexcharts": "3.27.1",
    "axios": "^0.22.0",
    "billboard.js": "3.0.3",
    "bulma": "0.9.3",
    "dayjs": "1.10.5",
    "dragula": "3.7.3",
    "dropzone": "5.9.2",
    "filepond": "4.28.2",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-size": "2.2.4",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type": "1.2.6",
    "filepond-plugin-image-crop": "2.0.6",
    "filepond-plugin-image-edit": "1.6.3",
    "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation": "1.0.11",
    "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "4.6.6",
    "filepond-plugin-image-resize": "2.0.10",
    "filepond-plugin-image-transform": "3.7.6",
    "firebase": "^9.6.2",
    "imask": "6.0.7",
    "mapbox-gl": "2.3.0",
    "markdown-it-emoji": "2.0.0",
    "notyf": "3.10.0",
    "nprogress": "0.2.0",
    "photoswipe": "4.1.3",
    "simple-datatables": "3.0.2",
    "simplebar": "6.0.0-beta.10",
    "simplebar-vue": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "sweet-modal-vue": "^2.0.0",
    "tiny-slider": "2.9.3",
    "tippy.js": "6.3.1",
    "trim-newlines": "^4.0.2",
    "tslib": "2.3.0",
    "v-calendar": "3.0.0-alpha.4",
    "vue": "3.0.11",
    "vue-i18n": "9.1.4",
    "vue-js-modal": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-router": "4.0.6",
    "vue-scrollto": "2.20.0",
    "vue-tippy": "6.0.0-alpha.29",
    "vue3-apexcharts": "1.4.0",
    "xmodal-vue": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@iconify/json": "1.1.358",
    "@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n": "2.2.1",
    "@types/dragula": "3.7.0",
    "@types/mapbox__mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^4.7.0",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/markdown-it": "12.0.2",
    "@types/node": "15.12.4",
    "@types/nprogress": "0.2.0",
    "@types/prismjs": "1.16.5",
    "@types/simplebar": "5.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.27.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.27.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "1.2.3",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "3.1.1",
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "cypress": "7.5.0",
    "eslint": "7.29.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-md": "1.0.19",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier-vue": "3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "7.11.1",
    "gray-matter": "4.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "11.0.0",
    "markdown-it": "12.0.6",
    "markdown-it-anchor": "8.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "plyr": "3.6.8",
    "prettier": "2.3.1",
    "prismjs": "^1.25.0",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "rollup": "2.52.1",
    "sass": "1.32.13",
    "stylelint": "^14.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "8.0.2",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^24.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.3.4",
    "vite": "2.3.8",
    "vite-imagetools": "3.6.8",
    "vite-plugin-components": "0.11.2",
    "vite-plugin-fonts": "0.2.2",
    "vite-plugin-imagemin": "^0.1.0",
    "vite-plugin-pages": "0.13.2",
    "vite-plugin-purge-icons": "0.7.0",
    "vite-plugin-pwa": "0.8.1",
    "vite-plugin-radar": "0.2.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.3.0",
    "yorkie": "2.0.0"
  },
  "gitHooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.ts": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "*.scss": [
      "stylelint",
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "*.md": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "prettier --write"
    ],
    "*.vue": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I am really confused about this. All other methods are working fine. Why not `defineExpose` is not working?

Comment: Do you get an error in browser? What is your package.json dependencies and devdependencies?

Comment: Yes, it shows me an error in the browser. package.json file included. Please check

Comment: Your vue version is old. Update it to the latest. defineExpose was added in 3.1.3 https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#313-2021-07-01

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Veture in VS Code, disable it for your project's workspace and use [Volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an eslint Problem. Above `defineExpose` you can add the comment:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
defineExpose({  })
```

or click the quick Fix button that shows up if you hover over `defineExpose`.